# A struct for putting in parameters passed around in a set of functions

Tags: c++, pointers, parameters, null, scope

I need the flexibility of being able to change parameters passed around to different functions, depending from where the call to the function happened, so I decided I'd put all my parameters in a struct, however most of these parameters are structs or classes themselves and I want to have the option of leaving them NULL, so I have to pass pointers to the structs/classes.

```
struct A
{
    otherB* b;  // NULL should be a valid value
    otherC* c;
};
```

However my question is now, passing A around these pointers will be the only thing copied, so if I did the following there would be a problem right?

```
void func(A& a) //non const cause I wanna change contents of A.
{
   a.b = new b();
}

A myA;
otherC somec; // all these are currently automatic variables in my pgm.
myA.c = &somec;

func(myA);  //myA goes out of scope? so I've lost all pointers assigned and since somec is out of scope too, I have a problem?
```

What would the best way to resolve something like this+  I want the flexibility of being able to pass NULL to any of my parameters, however not sure if using raw pointers everywhere is a good idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To solve the problem of resource management, you should use `boost::shared_ptr` (or `std::shared_ptr` in C++0x).

```
struct A
{
    boost::shared_ptr< otherB > b;
    boost::shared_ptr< otherC > c;
};

void func(A& a)
{
   a.b = boost::make_shared< otherB >();
}

A myA;
otherC somec;
myA.c = boost::shared_ptr< otherC >(&somec, null_deleter());

func(myA);
```

When `myA` goes out of scope, all resources are deallocated automatically. Since `somec` was allocated on the stack, we wrapped it in a `shared_ptr` that uses a `null_deleter`, that could look like this:

```
struct null_deleter {
    void operator()(void *) { }
};
```

This will *not* delete the object, it will do nothing (which is just what we want for stack-allocated objects). Keep in mind however, that you have to make sure that `somec` lives longer than `myA`, otherwise you will get access violations.

Comment: It prevents the `shared_ptr` from trying to delete a stack-allocated object, which would end in disaster.

Comment: But what's the point of shared_ptr to begin with, if you're using objects on the stack?  If something else can cause the object to be deleted, shared_ptr shouldn't be used.

Comment: @James: Flexibility. If you want your code to be able to deal with both, and you do not know up-front if objects will be stack-allocated or not.

Comment: Flexibility for what.  In this case, his problem is, or seems to be, that somec doesn't have a long enough lifetime.  Putting it in a shared_ptr isn't going to change that, and using the null_deleter will guarantee that shared_ptr's most important invariant will be violated.  If objects can be copied, there's almost never any point of allocating them dynamically, and if objects are never allocated dynamically, there's no sense in using shared_ptr.

Comment: @James: The [Boost Documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/smart_ptr/sp_techniques.html) lists some examples. I agree however, that it is generally not a smart idea to wrap statically allocated objects in a `shared_ptr`, and should only be done if you really know what you are doing.

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y statically allocated objects are less of an issue than local objects; normally, the static object will outlive the `shared_ptr`, so the guarantee that a `shared_ptr` always points to a non-destructed object (or is null) won't be invalidated.  It's having a `shared_ptr` point to a local object which doesn't work; the local object will be destructed when it goes out of scope, and the `shared_ptr` is left dangling.

Answer (score 1):

`boost::optional<>` Allows you to test if the field is set or not.

Simple example (will not compile, I've not even remotely tested it, in theory this is how it should work)

```
struct params
{
  boost::optional<int> a;
  boost::optional<foo> b;
  boost::optional<bar> c;
};

void func(params& p)
{
  if (p.a)
  {
    // do stuff with a
  }
  if (p.b)
  {
    // do stuff with b
  }
  if (p.c)
  { 
    // do stuff with c
  }
  else
    p.c = bar(); // again copy constructed and now initialized...
}

params p;
p.a = 1;
p.b = foo(); // copy constructed, however you can store a reference in the optional too.
// c is uninitialized

func(p);

// when p goes out of scope, everything is gone..
```

Answer (score 0):

You basically have to analyze *ownership*, i.e. who can allocate and who is responsible for deleting object once they no longer is used.

One thing that is important to remember is that if you mix dynamically allocated things and things placed on the stack, you simply can't apply `delete` on them, as it's not possible to delete things on the stack.

One way could be to only use `new` and define a destructor in `A` that deletes all it's pointers. Another way could be a place where you would register objects that later should be deleted. Or you could go the route of using existing reference-counting tools, as suggested in other answers.

Answer (score 0):

No, your idea of the scope of `myA` and `somec` are wrong. There's nothing wrong with what you have right now- although I personally think that references would be a superior option to pointers.

```
void func(A& a) //non const cause I wanna change contents of A.
{
    a.b = new b();
}


int main() {
    A myA;
    otherC somec; // all these are currently automatic variables in my pgm.
    myA.c = &somec;

    func(myA);
    // myA and somec are still perfectly in scope to be saved, or deleted, or w/e as you like
}
```

Comment: References cannot be null though, I need NULL to be a valid value!

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your description, but if you're having a problem
because somec is going out of scope, it can only be because func is
saving a copy of the pointer.  Don't do that: in funct, copy the object,
not the pointer.

PS: if most of the pointers are null most of the time, you should
consider using something like following syntactic sugar:

```
struct A
{
    //  pointer members...
    A() : // ... set all pointers to null...
    A& withB( B const& someB ) { otherB = &someB; return *this ; }
    A& withC( C const& someC ) { otherC = &someC; return *this ; }
    //  And so on for all of the rest of the pointers.
};

func( A().withC( somec ) );
```

Don't know if it's appropriate for your situation, but it's often
convenient.